# If there is no change in dll deployment, do we still see current date in bin folder?

Tags: .net, iis

I am deploying a. Net framework application through IIS, here I can not follow clean deployment, just Overwriting. What I can see in my deployment file structure is every folder has current date in date modified folder except bin. Is this an expected behavior?

I haven't tried clean deployment, only need insights about how dll works if no changes in metadata done.

Comment: Do you mean to redeploy the . Net framework application to iis? If so, you only need to copy the dll to iis, even you may not require deployment package. in general you can publish the site to a local folder and then copy it to server.

Comment: I am doing it through azure pipeline, just wanted to know about bin folder's behavior. I make sure there's no change in dlls metadata

Comment: Usually the Bin folder will not change, but If you change the .dll and write a new version of it to the Bin folder, the application detects the update and uses the new version of the .dll for new page requests from then on.

Comment: Could you talk more about the timestamp and date of the dll. If there's no chances made. If no new deployment happened for dll, do we still see current date and timestamp in all files or just old dates only reflects. Thanks for your extended help.

Comment: After you redeploy, the timestamp will also change accordingly.